# what is best to use include or include_once in connecting to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I was wondering what is the best to use in my php file in connecting to database include or include_once while my ajax script requesting it everytime.

ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var countTimer = setInterval(function () {
        codeValue();
    }, 500)

        function codeValue() {
            if ($('#emailCodeResult').val() !== '') {
                clearInterval(countTimer);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'codeTime.php',
                dataType: "JSON",
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    $("#count").val(result.user_code);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
});
```

codeTime.php

```
<?php

include_once('view/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$sql = "SELECT user_code FROM tbl_user";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$num_rows = $query->rowCount(); 

echo json_encode(array('user_code'=>$num_rows+1)); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`include_once`. If there are recursive imports, this function will make sure they are only imported once, but you really should have your connection as a global and not create a new connection every single time you refresh. Just create the connection to the database initially and when you refresh, just make a new `mysqli_query($connection, $query)` and when you are done use `mysqli_free_result($query)`.